# is it possible to catch errors in gnosis? sdk.eth.call

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-apps-sdk

I have tried with a try catch when await sdk.eth.call([...]) But this error on the screen is not possible to catch.

```
try {
    const txs: BaseTransaction[] = [
      {
        to: networkConfig.guardian,
        value: "0",
        data: GuardianContract.methods
          .setProtectionAdmin(token, adminWallet)
          .encodeABI(),
      },
    ];

    const params = { safeTxGas };

    return await sdk.txs.send({ txs, params });
  } catch (error) {
    // NO ERROR LOGGED
    console.log(error);
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please add more code how you trigger the method and with what parameters? Easiest would be a link to a github repo.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, i just added the request i am doing. I was expecting to see the error on the catch but no luck so far! The request is working because this error appears when there is not enough gas. Thanx!

Comment: In the example, you're doing `sdk.txs.send` and not `.call`. send returns a safeTxHash, it doesn't watch for on-chain events